# Iterate over list of Long causes a java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, loops, exception

Ok, i really don't know what happend

This is the code

```
List<Long> idProviders = form.getIdProviders();

for(Long idProvider: idProviders){...}
```

During the foreach i have this exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

and i can't figured out why this happend.
There is a similar question on stack overflow but there is no answer. Someone has an idea?

Comment: What are you doing in the "..." part?

Comment: i don't think the ... is pertinent because the exception happend before, however i call a service to retrieve a provider by id

Comment: What is `form`?  And what *exactly* does `getIdProviders()` return?

Comment: what do you mean "the exception happend before"? in the question it says "During the foreach " well which is it??

Comment: form is a Pojo, and the getIdProviders return a list of long. This is the getter/setter
`public List<Long> getIdProviders() {
  return this.idProviders;
 }

 public void setIdProviders(List<Long> idProviders) {
  this.idProviders = idProviders;
 }`

Comment: when i said that the exception happend before i mean that it happend at the beginning of iteration before the code inside the loop is executed. 
(excuse me for my bad english :( )

Comment: Is it possible you are passing a raw `List` (that may contain objects other than `Long`s) to `setIdProviders(List<Long> idProviders)`?

Comment: add this line before the `For` loop: `System.out.println(idProviders.get(0).getClass());` to see what is the actual type of the items in `idProviders`. in other words - do some basic **DEBUG**

Comment: Already tried Sharon, and it causes the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a scenario that can explain the exception you are seeing. It is caused by passing a raw `List` to `setIdProviders`:

```
List raw = new ArrayList();
raw.add ("some string");
YourFormClass form = new YourFormClass ();
form.setIdProviders (raw);
...
List<Long> idProviders = form.getIdProviders();
for(Long idProvider: idProviders) { // here an attempt is made to cast a String 
                                    // to a Long leading to ClassCastException
    ....
}
```

Comment: @OP Set a breakpoint before the loop and check the list contents. Most probably, there's a String inside, and most probably there's a compiler warning about generics / raw types related to the idProviders list.

Comment: Ok, i think your idea is the right idea Eran.
What i suppose it happend is that during form binding Spring Webflow uses raw list. 

Thank you for you help